# How to add ubuntu to windows 10 boot manager, but it will be in another hard drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I want it to be look like this:

[image]

I have an HDD and an SSD in my PC, I want to install Ubuntu to SSD, I have windows on HDD. I want to be able to boot ubuntu from the windows 10 uefi boot manager. How do I do it?

Comment: That is a Windows related question. You want help with Microsoft's bootloader... so I doubt we can help you with that. If it is at all possible. At least I assume you meant that W8/10 screen inside windows and not a grub replacement(?)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ?

Comment: Grub will still install a folder for UEFI boot in drive configured as sda.You do want to install Ubuntu in UEFI boo tmode. You can add this entry to Windows BCD: `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` Make sure SSD is gpt partitioned, and best to include an ESP - efi system partition, so you could configure it to boot without Windows drive. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't answer the question directly, since I'm not very familiar with configuring Windows boot tools. I'd like to point out some basic issues, though....

There are two types of programs, with some overlap between them, that are relevant:

- **Boot managers** -- These programs present a menu or other user interface to enable you to select which OS to boot.
- **Boot loaders** -- These programs load an OS kernel into memory and transfer control to it. Most boot loaders can load just one type of OS kernel (such as a Linux kernel or a Windows kernel) into memory.

Thus, the boot path goes from the firmware to a boot manager to a boot loader to the OS. One boot manager can hand off control to another, and there can be more complex boot paths if one stage or another returns to an earlier step.

Some programs, such as rEFIt, rEFInd, and gummiboot (now systemd-boot), are boot managers but not boot loaders. Others, such as the Linux EFI stub loader, are boot loaders but not boot managers. Still others, such as GRUB, are both boot managers and boot loaders. Some programs are boot loaders with limited boot management capabilities; for instance, ELILO and (under EFI) SYSLINUX can present menus that let you select which kernel to run, but they can't launch the boot loaders for other OSes.

My understanding of the Windows boot manager/loader is that it can chainload to another OS's boot loader or load a Windows kernel. It cannot load a Linux kernel directly, though (except perhaps via the EFI stub loader, but I don't know of anybody who's tried it that way). Thus, even if you succeed in configuring the Windows boot manager the way you want, you'll need a Linux boot loader in the mix.

One twist in all this is the Linux EFI stub loader, which is built into the kernel. The EFI stub loader turns the kernel into an EFI application that serves as a boot loader for the kernel itself. Thus, an EFI boot manager can fill a role very much like a boot loader, but *technically,* it's the kernel itself that's the boot loader. The nature of Linux kernel booting also means that you need to be able to pass options to the kernel, which few non-Linux boot managers make easy. Also, if you wanted to use this feature to have the Windows boot manager launch a Linux kernel, you'd need a way for the Windows boot manager to read the Linux kernel. Since the kernel is normally stored on a Linux-native filesystem, this would require changes to either move the kernel to a FAT partition or add an EFI driver for your Linux filesystem into the mix. Both are possible, but they add complications to the setup.

Note also that EFIs include their own boot managers, but not boot loaders. Unfortunately, most EFIs' boot manager user interfaces are quite poor, so most people prefer having something else available to fill that role.

Most experienced Linux users are familiar with GRUB and perhaps one or two other boot loaders or boot managers. Thus, you should have no problems getting advice on this site on how to configure GRUB, ELILO, SYSLINUX, gummiboot, or rEFInd to do what you want. (Note: I forked rEFInd from rEFIt, so if you care to use rEFInd, I'm the one to ask about it.) Expertise in configuring the Windows boot manager/loader is rarer here, though. If you really want to use the Windows tool, you should probably ask on a Windows forum.

There are about a bazillion questions and answers about boot manager and boot loader setup on this site, so please search if you care to use a more traditional Linux-friendly boot manager. If you can't find the answer to your question, feel free to ask another. (I recommend asking a new question rather than posting follow-ups, since your follow-up questions are likely to be very different from your original question and will require extensive new answers.)